# Duplicating rows and adding unique value from list for each duplication

Tags: r

I have a large dataset where each row is a model with an ID. Each row also has a column with a part number specified.

I am currently facing the scenario where I need to duplicate one row/model 10 times, so I can specify 10 part numbers associated with it. My thinking is that the rows should be duplicated and the part numbers assigned from a list.

Until now, I was able to do basic assignment like d$Part_Num[d$ID==8735] <- "1234"

For me, the quandary is how to duplicate them and then assign the part numbers, as I have previously been able to use the model ID to assign the part number. Once the rows are duplicated, however, the model ID will be duplicated that many times, too - making the ID non-unique.

Note: I will have to repeat this same process for both Models A, B, C, and D, using the same part number list, but I'm okay with just having to run the code multiple times, if adding that kind of repetition is inelegant.

Here is a toy df for the dataset:

```
structure(list(ID = 8735:8743, Model = c("Model_A", "Model_B", 
"Model_C", "Model_D", "Model_E", "Model_F", "Model_G", "Model_H", 
"Model_I"), Part_Num = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), row.names = 8615:8623, class = "data.frame")
```

And here is a toy list of part numbers:

```
list(1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239, 1230, 1231, 1232, 1233)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(ID = 8735:8743, Model = c("Model_A", "Model_B", 
                                               "Model_C", "Model_D", "Model_E", "Model_F", "Model_G", "Model_H", 
                                               "Model_I"), Part_Num = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
                                                                        NA_character_)), row.names = 8615:8623, class = "data.frame")
df <- df |> 
  mutate(Part_Num = map(Part_Num, function(.x) seq(1,4))) |> 
  unnest(Part_Num)
```

Comment: This is close but doesn't use the list of part numbers.